# Timepicker not displaying while editing records in dialog using syncfusion grid

Tags: angularjs, dialog, grid, timepicker, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion grid for displaying leave records.  There are fields- Attendance date, modified in time, modified out time, subject, reason for regularization of record. I have specified datatype, e-editType="datepicker" for attendance date and it is working correct on record edit and display. But, for modified in time and modified out time, i have specified e-editType="timepicker" and it is not rendering timepicker on record edit. I am using angularjs.Here is my code,

regularization.html

```
<div ng-controller="regularization_controller">
    <div>
        <h2>Regularisation Details

    </div>
    <div>

        <div ej-grid id="Grid" e-width="500px" e-datasource="data" e-columns="columns" e-allowpaging="true" e-editsettings-enablerowhover="true" e-editsettings-allowadding="true" e-editsettings-allowediting="true" e-editsettings-rowposition="bottom"
         e-editsettings-allowdeleting="true" e-editsettings-allowresizing="true" e-editsettings-showconfirmdialog="false" e-editsettings-editmode="mode"


         e-toolbarsettings-showtoolbar="true" e-toolbarsettings-toolbaritems="tools" e-locale="es-ES">

            <div e-columns>
                <div e-column e-field="sr" e-headertext="Sr.No." e-width="60px" e-isprimarykey="true" e-textalign="left"></div>
                <div e-column e-field="attendance_date" e-width="160px" e-editType="datepicker" e-headertext="Attendance Date" e-textalign="center" e-format="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}"></div>

                <div e-column e-field="modified_in_time" e-width="150px" e-editType="datetimepicker" e-format="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt}" e-headertext="Modified In Time" e-textalign="center"></div>
                <div e-column e-field="modified_out_time" e-width="150px" e-editType="datetimepicker" e-format="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt}" e-headertext="Modified Out Time" e-textalign="center"></div>



                <div e-column e-field="subject" e-width="120px" e-headertext="Subject" textalign="left"></div>

                <div e-column e-field="reason" e-width="120px" e-headertext="Reason" textalign="left"></div>

                <div e-column e-field="status" e-headertext="Status" e-width="100px"  e-edittype="dropdownedit" e-datasource="regularize_status" e-textalign="center"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

regularization_controller.js

```
app.controller('regularization_controller', function ($scope,$modal) {


 $scope.data = [{ "sr": "1", "attendance_date": "25-Feb-2015", "modified_in_time": "25-Feb-2015 09:00 AM", "modified_out_time": "25-Feb-2015 09:00 PM", "subject": "xyz", "reason": "abc", "status": "Applied" }, { "sr": "2", "attendance_date": "26-Feb-2015", "modified_in_time": "25-Feb-2015 09:00 AM", "modified_out_time": "25-Feb-2015 09:00 AM", "subject": "xyz", "reason": "abc", "status": "Applied" }];


 $scope.mode = ej.Grid.EditMode.Dialog;

    $scope.tools = [ej.Grid.ToolBarItems.Add, ej.Grid.ToolBarItems.Edit, ej.Grid.ToolBarItems.Delete, ej.Grid.ToolBarItems.Update, ej.Grid.ToolBarItems.Cancel];

    $scope.regularize_status = [{ text: "Applied", value: "Applied" }, { text: "Discard", value: "Discard" }];

});
```

Where am I wrong? Is there any solution. Please help. 
Thank you.

Comment: your html code is missing!

Answer (score 0):

The Syncfusion Grid have the following default `editType` for columns.

- DropDown
- DatePicker
- DateTimePicker
- Numeric
- String

You can use the `dialogtemplate` feature for include custom controls.

**Demo:** http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/grid/Editing/Dialogonlocaldata

**[Updated]**

```
<div id="Grid" ej-grid
       e-datasource="data" 
       e-editsettings-editmode="dialogtemplate" 
       e-editsettings-dialogeditortemplateid="#template"
       e-actioncomplete="onComplete">
    <div e-columns>
        <div e-column e-field="Hours"></div>
     </div e-columns>
</div>
```

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="template">
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
           <input type="text" name="Hours" value:{{:Hours}}/>   
          </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
</script>
```

**Events[JS]**

```
<script>
   function onComplete(args){
      if(args.requestType == "beginedit"||args.requestType == "add"){
          $("#GridHours").ejTimepicker({ value: args.data["Hours"] });
      }
   }
</script>
```

> **@Note:** While using dialog template, `edittype` property will not have any effect on setting the editor controls and it is the sole responsibility of the user to provide them in template and render them as control in `actioncomplete event`

See the above demo for how to use the dialog template.

Comment: I worked with the above code but it is not working for timepicker. How can i fix it for timepicker?

Comment: I am getting problem for editType= "timepicker", when i input the time timepicker not getting displayed. How can do this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am working with the same in angularjs. how can do the same in angularjs?

Comment: The above code is for angularjs only. If i misunderstood u, tell your requirement in detailed.

Comment: I have displayed regularization details in syncfusion grid with fields Attendance date, modified in time, modified out time, subject, reason. When i edit a record, dialog box is opened for corresponding record. Here,  for 'modified in time' field i am currently using e-editType="datetimepicker" but i want to input 'only time' (only timepicker popup) for the 'modiefied in time' field so that it will display time in '09:00 AM' format in grid column. How can do that?I have updated my code above. I am working in angularjs. Can you please tell me how can i do that?